# A Java method to return one and then the other of two repeatedly

Tags: java, string, methods

The method I want to define is to return a String of "BLACK" or "WHITE".
I am going to use this in a board game main method.

First time it returns "BLACK".
Second time it returns "BLACK".
Third time it returns "WHITE", and
Fourth time it returns "WHITE".

Then, it returns "BLACK", "WHITE", "BLACK", "WHITE", and so on, repeatedly.

How may I implement this?

I was going to define a Node class of String, create two Nodes with next and prev field pointing to each other, and return this._next._getDatum(); but I do not think it will work, and it makes my code too complicated.

Do you have any suggestions for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to return a different thing each time, your method needs to keep state. In Java, the state is kept using instance variables or class variables. Not knowing much about your design, here is a short implementation that flip-flops between `"BLACK"` and `"WHITE"`:

```
public class FlipFlop {
    boolean isWhite;
    public String getCurrent() {
        isWhite = !isWhite;
        return isWhite ? "WHITE" : "BLACK";
    }
}
```

Now calling `getCurrent` will alternate between `"BLACK"` and `"WHITE"`:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    FlipFlop ff = new FlipFlop();
    for (int i = 0; i != 10 ; i++) {
        System.out.println(ff.getCurrent());
    }
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/yVy3UG).

Comment: Great! Thank you! How may I make it return two "BLACK"s in the first two times and return two "WHITE"s in the next two times?

Comment: @user25409 Replace `boolean isWhite` with `int whiteCount`, and change `getCurrent` to `return (whiteCount++) % 4 > 1 ? "WHITE" : "BLACK"`

Comment: http://ideone.com/H5TEP4   this is my try. This works, but is this efficient?(I doubt because it keeps adding count after 2)

Comment: Oh... You already replied.. thank you!!

Comment: @user25409 You are right, incrementing past 4 could be dangerous because of overflow. I modified your demo to avoid overflows ([link](http://ideone.com/E4CsP4)).

Comment: Oh. My explanation was not correct. After returning two BLACKs and two WHITEs, it has to alternate BLACK and WHITE. The output at ideone.com/H5TEP4 is the desired output. How would I avoid overflows? I am thinking if(i<5){i++;} instead of just i++;. However it has to check the if condition every time it calls the method. Is there more effective way?

Comment: @user25409 To avoid overflows, replace `i++;` with `if (i < 4) i++;`

Answer (score 1):

**IF** you were to include this in a separate method, you could hold the number of moves done and use the modula of that amount to determine whether or not it's an even or odd amount. This will allow you to shift between two values.

Example:

```
private static int amount = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(amount < 10){
            if(amount % 2 == 0){
                System.out.println("White");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Black");
            }

            amount++;
        }
    }
```

This isn't placed in a method since it's more meant as a general way to solve this. You can easily put this in a method and return it as a value ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

this does not sound like a method at all.  just make a loop and place a simple IF check to toggle the value.